# POST request with parameters to Azure Web App Service (ASP .NET) receives additional Bad Request response

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, azure-web-app-service, iis-10

From 08.05.2022 my Azure Web App Service on POST request with parameters adds additional **Bad Request** responce and closes connection to normal responce

This is the normal behaviour (my developer server also acts as below, that excludes all sort of my errors)

```
POST /TestRequest HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.myserver.com
CONTENT-LENGTH:15
CONTENT-TYPE: APPLICATION/JSON; CHARSET=UTF-8

{"test":"data"}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Generator: Orchard
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 May 2022 19:03:39 GMT
Content-Length: 14

Test completed
```

This is unexpected behaviour

```
POST /TestRequest HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.myserver.com
CONTENT-LENGTH:15
CONTENT-TYPE: APPLICATION/JSON; CHARSET=UTF-8

{"test":"data"}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 10 May 2022 19:10:08 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Cache-Control: private
X-Generator: Orchard
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Test completedHTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 10 May 2022 19:10:08 GMT
```

POST Requests without parameters (with Content-Length: 0 ) does not have such bug.

I used putty for send requests and receive responces.

On the server side I have this method in controller:

```
public ActionResult TestRequest(object o) {
   return Content("Test completed");            
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
After some research i found, that core of the problem is **CONTENT-LENGTH:15** header.
`{"test":"data"}` contains exactly 15 characters. But in order web server to receive request you have to hit Enter (crlf) button (in putty).

For some reason, my iis and previuosly azure - does not accepted Enter as data, but now Azure web server treat Enter as part of request, thus it processes data (15 characters) and thinks that Enter (2 characters) - is another request.

I increased CONTENT-LENGTH:15 by two (crlf), and no Bad Request responce from web server received.

Moreover, previously web server in Azure App Service accepted **lf** line endings as a correct HTTP request, but now it requires only **crlf**.

Question: How to get back to the old web server behaviour?

Comment: [Could you provide a minimal reproducible unit of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I updated question with server side code, used to genetate responces.

Comment: I think the issue maybe not related with CRLF, so could you enable FREB in your web app, then you can reproduce the issue, and we need to capture the `400 bad request` record. If you want update the post, pls hide your sensitive info, tks.

Comment: I did as you said: 
1. Turned on Failed request tracing under My application -> Monitoring -> App Service logs 
2. Sent request with putty as in question (received Bad Request answer beside normal). Actually, did this several times.
3. Went to My application -> Diagnose and Solve -> Diagnostic Tools -> Failed Request Tracing Logs, and I can not see there any Status Code 400 errors (I can see others). Also I can see in other logs captured succesfull request to /TestRequest address

Comment: Ok， pls make sure enable these settings, when the issue occurs again, we can investagte it.

Comment: All this settings enabled now. I made some more tests. The result is that this Bad Request is not captured. To be more specific, I have 100+ devices, which sends POST requests to my portal. And all of them suddenly went offline (after 08.05.2022). I started  investigation of this problem and found this issue. My newer devices are online, because thay have more advanced firmware. I can provide you (in private) with link for actual /TestRequest link, and you can reproduce this issue. Also can provide you with any other information needed.